# Error al obtener valor maximo de campo

Tags: php

Quiero obtener el valor máximo del campo ***id***, pero me muestra error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be
> converted to string

```
public function obtenerMax() {
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as maximo FROM tabla";
    $bd = new ConexionDB();
    $stmt = $bd->query($sql);
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $row;
}
```

Cambié la línea del ***fetch***:

```
$row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Pero si quiero obtener dos valores del mismo ***select***:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as maximo, SUM(valor) as total FROM tabla";
```

Ya no puedo usar *fetchColumn*
Cómo obtengo esos valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás devolviendo el objeto resultado, no el dato concreto dentro del resultado. Usa $row.maximo

```
return $row.maximo;
```